# Integral of $1-\exp[-e^{-x^2}]$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need to evaluate $$I=\int_{\mathbb{R}}1-e^{-e^{-x^2 }}\textrm{d}x$$
I can do so via a Maclaurin expansion within the integral, then integrating term by term, 
$$I= \int_{\mathbb{R}}1-\left(1-e^{-x^2}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-2x^2}-\frac{1}{6}e^{-3x^2}+\dots\right)\textrm{d}x=\sqrt{\pi}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{i!\sqrt{i}}$$
I don't think the sum has a closed form. Is there either a way of doing this integral, or equivalently, a closed form?

Comment: Integral  does not converge on {0,\[Infinity]}. ?

Comment: It looks convergent to me.

Comment: Keep the 1-... inside or it doesn't converge

Comment: Also, the expression $\int a+b\, \mathrm dx$ is rather nonsensical, since everything in the integrand needs to be multiplied by $\mathrm dx$ – it should be $\int (a+b)\, \mathrm dx$.

Comment: Some people interpret $\int$ and $dx$ as parentheses

Comment: @GEdgar Oh, ok then.

Comment: Change variables $$I=\int_0^1\frac{1-e^{-y}}{y\sqrt{-\log y}}\;dy \approx 1.2851445$$

Comment: You have 0 and 1 as the limits because you split it into two parts, a positive and a negative. This is only part of it.